# How do I determine which value has been called from an array, to use in another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the below code which is called onclick, and want to be able to show a second image after a few seconds, depending on which one is chosen from the array - so for example if 1.png is shown, then I want to show 1s.png, 2.png then show 2s.png etc

```
    function displayImage () {
            var img_name = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png");
            var l = img_name.length;
            var rnd_no = Math.floor(l*Math.random());
            document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[rnd_no];
            }
```

How do I determine which image has been chosen from the array to then use in another function please ?

Comment: Are trying to choose image randomly, or orderly?

Comment: I choose the first image randomly, but then I would like to show a specific second image depending on what's chosen from the first, if that makes sense

Comment: `var img = document.getElementById("imgHolder"); img.src = img.src.replace(".png", "s.png");`

Comment: @Andreas - what would be an easy way of changing x.png to xs.png after say 3 seconds please? I think this may be a quicker way to achieve what I'm aiming for

Comment: Execute a function after x seconds? -> [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). But be aware that this may add unwanted behavior. Each call starts a new timer. So if there are multiple clicks, multiple timers will be created and each of them will be processed and change the image's `src`. Hence this needs some adjustments :)

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need a global var for knowing that function is running for the first time or not.

```
var alreadyRandom = false;

function displayImage()
{
  var img_name = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png");
  if(alreadyRandom)
  {
    // If the random for first time is done
    var rnd_no = img_name.indexOf(document.getElementById("imgHolder").getAttribute('src'));
    if(rnd_no === img_name.length-1)
    {
      // If the current image is the last one in array,
      // go back to the first one
      rnd_no = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      // Choose the next image in array
      rnd_no++;
    }
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[rnd_no];
  }
  else
  {
    var l = img_name.length;
    var rnd_no = Math.floor(l*Math.random());
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[rnd_no];
    alreadyRandom = true; // Tell the function not to random again
  }
  return img_name[rnd_no];
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kanejugahi/edit?html,js,console,output

Moreover, making the array global would make your function more efficient.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

I think it's important you understand how [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) work in JavaScript and how scope works.

What you need to do is you need to expose that information so that both functions have access. You have the array of images defined and you have already determined the random number so just make them available by declaring them outside of the function so now these variables are available. Defining variables in the global scope is generally bad practice but this is simply for teaching.

```js
var selectedImage; // defined outside so it is available for other functions

function displayImage() {
  var img_name = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png");
  var rnd_no = Math.floor(img_name.length * Math.random());
  selectedImage = img_name[rnd_no];
  document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = selectedImage;
}

function anotherFunction() {
  console.log(selectedImage);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Did you read the question clearly :)

Comment: It solves the **question he is asking** -- how do I reference a variable in different functions? If you are referring to the problem of how to swap the images, I'd rather have OP clarify that and I can change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand the question, you can use a return and make the image array global.

```
var img_name = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png");
var img_class = '';
//this function will return the index of the image in array
function displayImage () {
   var l = img_name.length;
   var rnd_no = Math.floor(l*Math.random());
   document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[rnd_no];
   return rnd_no;
}

var nextimage;
function showImages(){
     //your logic to show the next image here
     nextimage = (displayImage ()+1)%img_name.length;
     var myVar = setInterval(function(){
     if(img_class==''){
        document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[nextimage];
        img_class = 's';
     }else{
        var img_arr = img_name[nextimage].split(".");
        if(img_arr.length===2){
           document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_arr[0]+"s."+img_arr[1];
        }

        img_class = '';
        nextimage = (nextimage+1)%img_name.length;
     }


   }, 1000);
}
```

```js
var img_name = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png");
    var img_class = '';
    //this function will return the index of the image in array
    function displayImage () {
    var l = img_name.length;
    var rnd_no = Math.floor(l*Math.random());
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").src = img_name[rnd_no];
    return rnd_no;
    }

    var nextimage;
    function showImages(){
        //your logic to show the next image here
        nextimage = (displayImage ()+1)%img_name.length;
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){
        if(img_class==''){
            document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML = img_name[nextimage];
            img_class = 's';
        }else{
            var img_arr = img_name[nextimage].split(".");
            if(img_arr.length===2){
            document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML = img_arr[0]+"s."+img_arr[1];
            }

            img_class = '';
            nextimage = (nextimage+1)%img_name.length;
        }


    }, 1000);
    }
    showImages();
```

```html
<div id="imgHolder"></div>
```

Comment: Putting it outside only make the function more efficient, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Noobit What he is asking is how to determine which value has been called to use it in another function. Btw I've edited the answer to solve, not sure it's the most efficient one.

Answer (score -2):

Mayve something like this?

```
var images = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png"];
function displayImage () {
    var dom = document.getElementById("imgHolder");
    if ( images.indexOf(dom.src) >=0 ) {
        dom.src = dom.src.replace(".png", "s.png"); // Seems like a stupid way to do this
        return;
    }
    var l = images.length;
    dom.src = images[Math.floor(l*Math.random())];
}
```

Comment: _"// Seems like a stupid way to do this"_ Then why did you add my comment as an answer without fixing the name of the variables correctly?

Comment: Sorry. I was reading something else at the time X_X, but my comment still stands =P